# CORS request error even thought it's enabled in the .Net Core back end

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have a test app, which I want to send a request and get a token, but anyway I can't get it due to the cross request error in my back end in the configuration I have:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {


        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
        }));
```

and added the following on the Configure part:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

but still getting the error saying  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Remove this and try again: ```.AllowCredentials().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");```

Comment: @Hadi i did that,still does not work,the same error

Comment: So please share your middlewares in the "configure" method in the startup.cs.

Comment: @Hadi edited my post with that

Comment: Try using ```app.UseCors("MyPolicy");``` before ```app.UseAuthentication();```

Comment: @Hadi tried that but did not work,it has nothing to do with the angular part?

Comment: @moris62, sometimes i have a CORS error with **asp.net-core + angular** project because of other problem. But actually it works fine. I wrote an answer how i did it below

Answer (score 0):

Put `services.AddCors` in the top of your `ConfigureSevices` method, then configure cors that way:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
             builder.AllowCredentials()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200");
        }));
```

In `Configure` method add `app.UseCors("MyPolicy");` at the top of method too. That works fine for me, but before i tried a lot of variants which did not.

Comment: i get Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44361/api/Auth/token/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Try to configure with **https** also, i edited my answer

Comment: nfrom origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  the same error its really irritating

Comment: @moris62, ok let try to put this attribute before your controller and test again:
`[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]`

Comment: already added that,but seems it has nothing to do with that,could it be from Angular side?

Comment: @moris62. I dont think so. I got the same problem and it started work after settings i sent in answer. Only differense i see that you use `"MyPolicy"` everywhere, but i did as it should be from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1), with `readonly string MyPolicy= "_myPolicy";` and put it everywhere below