# Posting to .NET Core WebAPI with ReactJS frontend and fetch api

Tags: reactjs, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

I am learning how to build a .NET Core web api so I decided to try a simple POST request to the backend with fetch() in the frontend.

Front-end

```
const Form = () => {
  const submission = {
    contactNumber: "123153214",
    name: "JJ Lin",
    group: 5,
    tableId: 3,
    isAccompanied: true,
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/guest-submission", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(submission),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log("not ok" + response.status);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click here to submit</button>;
};
```

On the backend, I have a guest class:

```
    public class Guest
    {
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Group Group { get; set; }
        public int TableId { get; set; }
        public bool IsAccompanied { get; set; }
    }
```

With my controller as such:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitGuest([FromBody]Guest guestInput)
        {

            var guest = new Guest
            {
                ContactNumber = guestInput.ContactNumber,
                Name = guestInput.Name,
                Group = guestInput.Group,
                TableId = guestInput.TableId,
                IsAccompanied = guestInput.IsAccompanied
            };
            Console.WriteLine(guest.Name);

            return Ok();
        }
```

Using Postman worked for me. But using the react frontend I built, I kept receiving a 415 error.

Can someone enlighten me pls? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Try adding `'Accept': 'application/json'` to your header, right before the Content-Type

Answer (score 0):

I just commented **mode: "no-cors"** and it is working (I changed the api url and submission object for testing). Moreover, you are using POST call but in .then you log "not ok" if status is not 200 which is not ok ;) as POST call returns 201 for successful create data on the server.

```
import React from "react";
const Form = () => {
    const submission = {
        title: 'This is title',
        body: 'This is body',
        userId: 1
    };
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
            method: "POST",
            // mode: "no-cors",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(submission),
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response, 'response');
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log("not ok" + response.status);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };

    return <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click here to submit</button>;
};

export default Form
```

**Update:**

You need to enable CORS in startup. On your startup.cs file, add the following code on ConfigureServices function before the line 'services.AddControllers();'

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost: 3000");
                });
        });  
    }
```

And on your Configure method of Startup, add the below code: app.UseCors();

Comment: thanks @Khabir. The submission is blocked when I comment out no-cors because my backend is running on localhost:5001 vs localhost:3000 on the front-end. How can I whitelist 3000 on my backend? Do you know?

Comment: @aijnij, follow this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443057/cors-request-error-even-thought-its-enabled-in-the-net-core-back-end/61443550#61443550), but use `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:{your frontend port here}")`

Comment: @aijnij I have added the example how you allow your url. Please check it